# Унарный плюс

Tags: java, c++

Вопрос на злобу дня: для чего нужен унарный плюс? Долго думал, но ничего полезного кроме как перегрузить его, не нашел. В остальном - только потенциальные проблемы.

```
struct dummy
{
   explicit dummy(int i)
      :a(i){}
   int a;
};

dummy operator+(dummy const& r, dummy const& l)
{
   return dummy(r.a + l.a);
}

dummy operator+(dummy const& r)
{
   format_drive_C_and_kill_a_kitty();   
   return dummy(r.a);
}

int main()
{
   dummy a(3), b(7);
   dummy c = + b; //вот тут случайно опечатались, должно быть a + b
}
```

Update: а если нельзя перегрузить? (Java например)

Comment: Раз вы задаете такие вопросы, то, видимо, плохо понимаете сущность и мощь перегрузки операций.

Comment: Очевидно, если есть вопрос - значит что-то непонятно ;) Конкретно тут не совсем понятен смысл оператора +, а_не_перегрузки_операторов. Рас уж так, то апдейт вопросу.

Comment: Перегрузка оператора (имхо) это зло! Не зря в Java таких перлов нет.

Answer (score 2):

[www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/3279423.flat.aspx](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/3279423.flat.aspx)

Посмотрите здесь, я сам запутался, когда разбирался)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что по историческим соображениям. Совместимость представления чисел на разных носителях.

Накопились когда-то (во времена Кобола, Фортрана и Алгола) наборы данных вида

```
-1.0 +2.0 -2.1 +3.1 ...
```

Понятно, что надо предусмотреть возможность их обработки. 
И ведь логично, когда числа вне и внутри программы можно записывать одинаково.

Тем более, что формальная грамматика, используемая при построении компилятора от унарного плюса не усложняется.